# USB modem have mutiple ports, what are they?

Tags: usb, gsm, at-command, modem

I'm currently learning about modems and AT commands. I can somehow can get it to works.

But I'm curious, when I plugged my USB, it shows up as /dev/ttyUSB0, /dev/ttyUSB1, /dev/ttyUSB2. When I tried using them, only /dev/ttyUSB1 and /dev/ttyUSB2 responded to my AT commands. And for some commands (like AT+CUSD), when I send it to /dev/ttyUSB1, the response comes back from /dev/ttyUSB2.

What are the differences between these three interfaces? I've searched everywhere but I can't find any clue.